# Is there an algorithm to create groups while Minimizing Mean absolute deviation within the group?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, grouping

I have a list of data that is weights associated with a cost, sorted by weight. The weights do not determine the costs.

I am looking to break this data into ranges of weights (7 in my case, but I would prefer a generalized solution) such that the average deviation from the mean for the costs within a group is minimized. The groups must not contain only one member or only identical members.

For example, if you were to break the following data set into two groups:

| number | weight | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 15 |
| 2 | 15 | 17 |
| 3 | 20 | 23 |
| 4 | 25 | 24 |
| 5 | 30 | 31 |
| 6 | 35 | 37 |

The correct grouping would be {15, 17} and {23,24,31,37}.

My initial thoughts on an algorithm are to begin by creating arbitrary groupings and then examining the cutoffs between each group to determine whether increasing or decreasing them would cause a greater decrease in total Mean absolute deviation. I would also set a minimum decrease that must be met in order to make any moves.

If no moves are made, or if a move is repeated, that cutoff is considered fixed. I have found this algorithm seems to get stuck a lot when there are a lot of costs that are similar, as well as tending to prefer a couple of small groups, but I am unsure if this is due to the test datasets I constructed, or if there is a flaw in the algorithm.

Comment: It would help if you posted the mathematical formula, or the actual code, that you use to compute the "total mean absolute deviation".

Comment: By total mean absolute deviation, I meant the sum of the mean absolute deviations for all the groups. Within a group the mean absolute deviation is the average of average of the absolute deviations from the mean of the group. I.e. Σ|x - m(X)| / n where x is an element of X, a group with n elements

Comment: *"tending to prefer a couple of small groups"* I don't think that's a problem with your algorithm. I think it follows from the definition of *"total mean absolute deviation"*. There are two ways to minimize the mean absolute deviation of a group, either use a small group so that all the values are close together, or use a large group because the sum is divided by a large `n`. Medium-sized groups, where values are farther from the mean, and `n` is smaller, are not desirable.

Comment: A minimax objective (minimize the maximum average) seems to make the group sizes closer to each other.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved as a set-covering problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). The mathematical model can look like:

[image]

The objective minimizes the sum of the average deviations from the means. The first constraint says: we need to cover item k exactly once. The second constraint says we need to select 2 groups. This is a linear Mixed Integer Programming model.

Using

```
----     33 PARAMETER v  values

i1 15.000,    i2 17.000,    i3 23.000,    i4 24.000,    i5 31.000,    i6 37.000
```

the `argdev[i,j]` constants are precalculated as:

```
----     33 PARAMETER avgdev  average absolute deviations from mean in group

            i2          i3          i4          i5          i6

i1       1.000       3.111       3.750       4.800       6.333
i2                   3.000       2.889       3.750       6.080
i3                               0.500       3.333       5.250
i4                                           3.500       4.444
i5                                                       3.000
```

The constant `ng=2` says we want two groups.

When we solve this with a MIP solver, we see:

```
----     53 VARIABLE x.L  1 if group i..j is selected, 0 otherwise

i1.i2 1
i3.i6 1


----     53 VARIABLE z.L                   =        6.250  objective
```

so we select group {i1,i2} and {i3,i4,i5,i6}.

To get a feeling about performance, I tried a problem with 500 items and 10 groups and random data. That took about a minute to solve to proven optimality. The grouping looked like:

```
----     73 PARAMETER results  

               avgdev   groupsize

i1  .i10       24.000      10.000
i11 .i37       72.568      27.000
i38 .i48       19.950      11.000
i49 .i73       57.885      25.000
i74 .i90       29.197      17.000
i91 .i133      98.326      43.000
i134.i234     284.310     101.000
i235.i297     176.080      63.000
i298.i425     365.832     128.000
i426.i500     207.209      75.000
```

If we want, we can add further constraints on the group size (e.g. at least 5, at most 100). To forbid groups i..j with zero avgdev[i,j] is not difficult to add. An alternative objective would be to minimize the largest `avgdev[i,j]`. An alternative approach could be to use a dynamic programming algorithm.

This is not really an "algorithm" but rather a "model". It sometimes helps to think about a problem in this way.